# Contradiction between memorylessness of random walk to straight forward calculation

Tags: probability, expected-value

> A drunk person is in place $x=0$ in time $t=0$. Every second he moves
>   forward one meter in a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ or stays in his
>   place in a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ (his decisions are
>   independent). In addition, every second he can pass out in a
>   probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ (also independently).
>
> Mark: $X$ - the distance he reaches.

A. Find the expected value of $X$.

B. Given he reaches at least 2 meters, find the expected value of $X$.

My solution:

A. $Y$ - number of seconds until he passes out. $Y\sim Geo(\frac{1}{2})$

$X|Y\sim Bin(y,\frac{1}{2})$

Therefore: $E(X) 
=E(E(X|Y))=E(\frac{Y}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot E(Y)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot2=1$

B. Since it is a random walk, $E(X|X\ge2)=E(X)+2=3$

But:

$P(X=0)=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X=0|Y=y)\cdot P(Y=y)=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{y}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{y-1}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{2y}=\frac{1}{3}$

$P(X=1)=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X=1|Y=y)\cdot P(Y=y)=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\binom{y}{1}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{y-1}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{y-1}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{2y}=\frac{4}{9}$

$\Rightarrow P(X\ge2)=1-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{4}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$

$E(X)=\sum_{x\in Rx}x\cdot P(X=x)=E(X|X=0)\cdot P(X=0)+E(X|X=1)\cdot P(X=1)+E(X|X\ge2)\cdot P(X=2)$

So, $1=0+\frac{4}{9}+\frac{2}{9}\cdot E(X|X\ge2)$ and $E(X|X\ge2)=2.5$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does he pass out before or after the move (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume the person passes out (or not) *after* the move, so the game has at least one move.  Now, when the person reaches $X=2$, there is a 50% probability that the game ends immediately, as he will pass out immediately after reaching $X=2$; if he doesn't, then, as you have realized, the game effectively restarts at $X=2$.  So, we have:

$$\mathbb{E}X|X\geq2 = 2 + {1 \over 2}\mathbb{E}X = 2.5$$

which matches your second derivation.

If, on the other hand, the person passes out before the move, there is, essentially, one extra "pass out" check at the beginning of the game.  After that, the game proceeds as in the first case - move decision, pass out check, move decision, etc.  Consequently, the expected distance the person travels is half what it is in the first case:  $\mathbb{E}X = 1/2$, but the expected distance the person travels conditional upon reaching $X=2$ is still $2.5$.